# I must take an element from HTML that It not the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose you have this HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="visible-sm-inline visible-md-inline visible-lg-inline">Sort by</span>
        <span class="visible-xs-inline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li><a href="#" class="newest_to_oldest" data-sort="newest_to_oldest"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Newest to Oldest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="oldest_to_newest" data-sort="oldest_to_newest"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Oldest to Newest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="most_posts" data-sort="most_posts"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Most posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="zero" data-sort="zero"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Post senza risposta</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="most_views" data-sort="most_views"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> Most Views</a></li></ul>
```

I need to detect when I click on other  tag except:

```
<a href="#" class="most_views" data-sort="most_views"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> Most Views</a></li></ul>
```

I tried this in jQuery:

```
    $('a[data-sort!="most_views"]').click(function(){
console.log("HI");
    });
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Whats the issue? Your code should work https://jsfiddle.net/mogp8bkk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-sort]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':not([data-sort="most_views"])')) {
      console.log('not most views');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li><a href="#" class="newest_to_oldest" data-sort="newest_to_oldest"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Newest to Oldest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="oldest_to_newest" data-sort="oldest_to_newest"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Oldest to Newest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="most_posts" data-sort="most_posts"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Most posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="zero" data-sort="zero"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Post senza risposta</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="most_views" data-sort="most_views"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> Most Views</a></li></ul>
```

or

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-sort]:not([data-sort="most_views"])').click(function() {
    console.log('not most views');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li><a href="#" class="newest_to_oldest" data-sort="newest_to_oldest"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Newest to Oldest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="oldest_to_newest" data-sort="oldest_to_newest"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Oldest to Newest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="most_posts" data-sort="most_posts"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Most posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="zero" data-sort="zero"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Post senza risposta</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="most_views" data-sort="most_views"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> Most Views</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: How is it different than OP's code? Maybe issue just comes from missing ready wrapper but...

Comment: @A.Wolff `[attr!="text"]` work if there is no attr attribute. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: Ah ok, i see what you mean but then the question was really unclear imho

Comment: The code is work. But now I need to take when I click on "most_views" so my code jquery became $('a[data-sort]').click(function() {

     if ($(this).is('[data-sort="most_views"]')) {
      $('a[data-sort="newest_to_oldest"]').parent().parent().append('<li><a href="#" class="most_views" data-sort="most_views"><i class="fa fa-fw"></i> Most Views</a></li>');
     }
    }); But it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Add a second class to every element apart from the one you don't want and use that class to detect the onclick event.